# Link validator: external URLs containing ampersands not working

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

When inserting external links via CKEditor, ampersands (`&`) are converted to `&amp;` in the source code. That's fine for the frontend but the link validator seems to have problems with the ampersand, as it tries to verify the link containing the ampersand (which doesn't work).

Is there something wrong with my CKEditor configuration or can I configure link validator so it replaces `&amp;` with `&`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As & to & for links in HTML is absolutely correct, linkvalidator should urldecode() this before accessing the URL. 
I suggest to open a bug report at https://forge.typo3.org

Comment: Thanks, I opened an issue (https://forge.typo3.org/issues/89682).